# from tools import tasks, ImportError: cannot import name tasks

Tags: python, pyvmomi

Trying to execute this [sample code](http://www.tagwith.com/question_346372_how-to-create-a-vm-not-clone-with-a-vmdk-disk-attached-using-pyvmomi/) as I need to create a vm using `pyvmomi`.
But the execution fails at the start in `from tools import tasks` with the error:  **ImportError: cannot import name tasks**.

I have tried for long but could not resolve the error. I have python 2.7 on centOS 6.4

tools module is installed but do not have `tasks.py` inside `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tools/`

Not sure which tools packages have to be installed.
Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

The module you want is this one https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/tree/master/samples/tools not the module you obtain installing it through pip.

It's a sample module that's why maybe you got confused. In the link you provided probably they are using this sample module.